# Is it possible to redownload enterprise apps through Apple ID's?

Tags: ios-appstore, apple-id, enterprise

To me, it seems as if this should be possible. With a normal app, you can go to 'Purchased' and re-download any previously downloaded apps.

Is it possible to do the same with an enterprise app which was ***not*** downloaded through the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if it was not originally purchased/downloaded from the Apple App Store, you will not find it in the *Purchased* section.

Usually, enterprise apps are distributed from that company's 'app store' only.  If they are deleted from your iOS device, you can revisit the company app store and re-download the app again.  It's up to that company if they want to have a *Purchased* tab or some other way of seeing previously downloaded apps.